# HANA Dependancy

Tags: sql, hana

How to find the View Dependency ..For ex i created one view A(Using Table1) and used the View A in View B along with Table2..

Is  there a way to find the list of the views used in any View ..

For Ex: If i pass View B then i should get View A ,Table1 and Table2

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can get that from `sys.object_dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

Your question assumes static dependencies of views and tables. This is only partly true as whether or not a specific dependent object is 'touched' during the execution of a query depends on the query itself.
For example if a view consists of a join that can be reduced to a single table access when no column of the joined table is requested, then there is no runtime dependency.
To see what objects actually get 'touched' by a query, the `EXPLAIN PLAN` tool is the best option.